# Why can't I make a circle with border-radius?

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  background-color: green;
  height: 900px;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 4px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div:hover {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 1px blue;
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  div {
    background-color: aqua;
    color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
  }
  body {
    background-color: chocolate
  }
}

.divas {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . </div>
<div class="divas"></div>
```

Hello I would like to make a perfectly rounded circle. I tried creating it with border-radius , but it doesn't allow me to create a perfect circle. Can someone explain me why? I tried changing padding and such but it doesn't work anyways.? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to create circle with border-radius then **height and width should be same** for the div which you are applying border-radius

Then only border-radius will look like circle

Example

```css
#circle{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

For a perfect circle you need an element with the same height and width. You also only have a `border-radius:50px` instead of `border-radius:50%` defined.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  background-color: green;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
 padding: 25px 28px 28px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 4px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 60px;
}

div:hover {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 1px blue;
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  div {
    background-color: aqua;
    color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
  }
  body {
    background-color: chocolate
  }
}

.divas {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
This is text.<br> This is text. This is text. This is text. This is text. This is text.
</div>
<div class="divas"></div>
```

Comment: The next question, of course, is how to ensure that the text is shown without wasting a lot of space within the circle... :-)

Comment: True, well there are many possible approaches to this. In many cases I find using text-align: center and centering the text vertically and horizontally to be sufficient. Using [shape-outside](https://codepen.io/noahblon/pen/pjvPPN) is also an interesting option, but sadly it's not yet enabled by default in Firefox.

Comment: So I should just do text-align:center or something else with it?

Comment: Well, that kind of depends. Is the textcontent of the circle dynamic? Then I think the only *100%* consistent method would be to resort to JS. For static content I think you'll be good to go if you fiddle around with the values. In the codesnippet I added some padding and put appropriate line breaks where neccessary to "fake" the circular text wrap in addition to centering the textdiv and aligning the text to the center.

Answer (score 1):

Div with same height and width

border-radius is half the width gives a circle.

```css
.mycircle {
    background-color: green;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mycircle"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `aspect-ratio` CSS' property. Compatible with all major browsers...

```css
.fixed-units {
  width: 150px;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #bada55;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.dynamic-units {
  width: 50%;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #daba55;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<label>For Fixed Units</label>
<div class="fixed-units"></div>

<br>
<label>For Dynamic Units</label>
<div class="dynamic-units"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Creating a circle in css object should have same width and height
add width:300px; to .divas class.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make a perfect circle, you need to set width and height equal. If you do so by CSS you need to define them both in 'px', rather than '%' since the window width & height may vary from device to device. Now set border-radius as 50%. Below is the CSS:

```css
div {
  background-color: green;
  height: 900px;
  width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 4px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**In case your with is dependent on the window's width** (as you have used %), you can set height equal to width using javascript. Here is how to do it.

**HTML**

```html
<div></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
var requiredWidth = window.innerWidth * (0.5); //window width excluding scrollbar.
var div = document.querySelector('div');
div.style.width = requiredWidth + 'px';
div.style.height = requiredWidth + 'px';
```

Now that you have defined height and width using javascript, set border-radius to 50% in your CSS.

**CSS**

```css
div {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a circle with border-radius then height and width should be the same for the element which you are applying `border-radius:100%`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  background-color: green;
  height: 600px;
  width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 90px;
  border: 4px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

div:hover {
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 1px blue;
}

@media screen and (max-width:600px) {
  div {
    background-color: aqua;
    color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
  }
  body {
    background-color: chocolate
  }
}

.divas {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20%;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . This is text . </div>
<div class="divas"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `border-radius: 100%` and have your height and width be equal.